# MySQL: Case When alternative / correct statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
Order    | UserID | Date       | Channel |
------------------------------------------
1        | 1      | 2015/01/01 | Direct  |
2        | 1      | 2015/01/02 | Natural |
3        | 1      | 2015/01/03 | PPC     |
4        | 1      | 2015/01/04 | Direct  |
1        | 2      | 2015/01/01 | Natural |
2        | 2      | 2015/01/02 | Natural |
1        | 3      | 2015/01/01 | Direct  |
2        | 3      | 2015/01/02 | Natural |
3        | 3      | 2015/01/03 | PPC     |
1        | 4      | 2015/01/01 | Natural |
2        | 4      | 2015/01/02 | PPC     |
3        | 4      | 2015/01/03 | Direct  |
4        | 4      | 2015/01/04 | Natural |
```

I would like to remove complete UserIDs where Order = 1 is not 'Natural'.
In other words, I would like to remove users which didn't start their website journeys through 'Natural' channel.

This is the table I would like to see after:

```
Order    | UserID | Date       | Channel |
------------------------------------------
1        | 2      | 2015/01/01 | Natural |
2        | 2      | 2015/01/02 | Natural |
1        | 4      | 2015/01/01 | Natural |
2        | 4      | 2015/01/02 | PPC     |
3        | 4      | 2015/01/03 | Direct  |
4        | 4      | 2015/01/04 | Natural |
```

I've tried to use CASE WHEN statement but with poor result:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Order = 1
        WHEN Channel = 'Natural'
    END
FROM tablename
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is not for row filtering.  You need `WHERE` with `EXIST` sub-query or some functional equivalent.

Comment: @ PM 77-1 Sorry to bother, but any chance for actual query example?

Comment: Nope. You need to learn some SQL first. I gave you enough of a clue to start.

Comment: SELECT <The columns you want> FROM <tablename> WHERE EXISTS (some condition). Seriously, you should find a tutorial online and work your way through it. This is a pretty basic SQL query.

Comment: Thanks both, I guess it is either late hour or my SQL level of knowladge...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Where` clause to filter records from table not `case` statement

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE Order = 1
  AND Channel <> 'Natural'
```